# Passing parameters using |

Tags: c++

I recently started to learn some OpenGL stuff and I saw that there are some functions used by freeGLUT that take in only one parameter but like more values can be passed. For example `glutInitDisplayMode(unsigned int displayMode);` I can see it takes in only one unsigned integer but I can also write something like `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);` using `|` symbol and it works perfectly fine. So I told myself let's write some example so we can see what happens:

```
#include <iostream>

void function(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    function(3 | 6);
    function(3 | 6 | 8);
    function(3 | 6 | 9 | 5);
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs are: 7 15 15 . I am really confused. Could someone tell me how this `|` works and what it is used for?

Comment: It is a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

Comment: Try find out and learn about binary operators in C++, beacuse this is really fundamental knowledge

Comment: Someone closed this before I had a chance to answer it properly. This is indeed a valid question, despite being a *beginner* question. Way to go, question police.

Comment: @zxq9: Indeed it is a valid question; but it's already been asked and answered, so should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "bitwise OR" operator.  The result is the "OR" between the bits in the 2 operands.

Search for it on google, or:

Check out the following page: [tutorial on bitwise operators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Hope that will explain it more in detail.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon (what if the linked page is removed in the future?) Please provide self-contained information in the answer.